# Is there is a way to DM someone that is mentioned in a message with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**Is there is a way to DM someone that is mentioned in a message with discord.js?**

this is my code.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) {return}
  let person = message.content.mentions
  person.send("My message")
})
```

it's not working for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mentions` is not a valid property of `content`. You're looking for [`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) which is a [`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) object.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    // Getting the first mentioned user in the message.
    const person = message.mentions.users.first();
    // Checking if any user was mentioned.
    if (!person) return message.reply("Please mention someone.");

    person.send("Hello!").then(() => {
        message.reply(`Message sent to ${person.tag}`);
    }).catch(error => {
        message.reply(`Couldn't send the message to ${person.tag}. | ${error}`);
    });
});
```